# VueJS Process shows undefined

Tags: vue.js

Have an app that's built in Vue. Been trying to figure this out for a while. Im unable to access process variables. Have tried multiple things so far.

- ensured my .env file is in the root directory
- have run build and serve every-time I add variables to .env file
- installed dotenv

Im using vue/cli 4.3.1
What am i missing?

[Edits]

- Right now, my .env has only 1 entry
  [image]
- Trying to access it in the created() method

  created: function() {
  console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE);
  }
- Here is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: share a screenshot of your file structure?

Comment: You should show the contents of the `.env` file and also an example of how you're trying to access them

Comment: I have updated the main post with screenshots

Answer (score 1):

## If `process` is `undefined`

#### Check your NodeJs Version

You might want to update your NodeJs Version (and npm), remove the `node_modules` folder and hit `npm install` again. I read a few cases where this helped.

#### Recreate the `env` file

The `.env` file might be faulty in some way. Try deleting the file and re-creating it using console (like `touch .env` on linux)

## If Variables are `undefined`

#### Check if you have the correct naming: `VUE_APP_MYVAR` instead of `MYVAR`

The most common error when it comes to `Environment Variables` inside `Vue` is the naming. When using `env` you have to prefix all variables with `VUE_APP_`, otherwise Vue won't include them.

More background info here : https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html. From the docs

> Note that only NODE_ENV, BASE_URL, and variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. It is to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

Make sure to **not include** any secrets (such as private API keys) in your app! Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.

Comment: i made sure to add VUE_APP_ to the variables.. but what bothers me is that process shows up as undefined. its not that the specific variable is undefined or missing..

Comment: Oh so I misunderstood the question my bad ! 
`process` is undefined or `process.env` ?

Comment: Process is undefined.

Comment: I added two additional troubleshooting ideas for undefined `process` 

Comment: I have already tried creating the file using touch .env. I however haven’t tried removing node_modules and installing again. Will try that. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Tried deleting and reinstalling node modules.. still the same error.. :(

Comment: Can you include the exact error you get in your question, also please include the actual part where and how you use it ( you added the usage but it actually just looks like an example )

Comment: If you create a repo to look at I am willing to test it locally to see it it happens for me as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227565/discussion-between-cnatraj-and-pascal-lamers).

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers might be helpful, the eventual solution to this problem for me was, to actually only **read the values at `mounted`**. I am unsure why exactly, but this worked for me:

```
mounted: function (): void {
    console.log('App version: ' + process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION);
    console.log('Environment: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);        
},
```

For showing them in the templated HTML output, I had to make sure, that `undefined` did not crash the process, and I have done it (the ugly way) like this (note the **extra empty strings at the beginning** in the computed functions):

```
<p title="App info">
    <small>App version: {{ version }} ({{ environment }})</small>
</p>
//....
computed: {
    version(): string {
        return '' + process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION;
    },

    environment(): string {
        return '' + process?.env?.NODE_ENV;
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the suggestions poster here and in other threads, but still getting process is undefined error.
For those wondering what I did, I am using window. webpackhotupdate To determine if I'm dealing with a prod build or dev build. webpackhotupdate Is true in dev builds.

Not the most elegant but gets the job done for now.